Why is my ASP.NET page automatically redirecting to home page?
I am brand new to ASP.NET development.  I'm trying to get my org's app running in a new environment.  Users can log in, but instead of being taken to their landing page, the login page reappears.  Through logging I can confirm that the landing page's Page_Load function terminates correctly, and I'm using the exact same code that works in other environments.  Also, there's no explicit Redirect() in the code path.  I'm wondering the there's an IIS issue.  What are some things I could look at in IIS to help me find the issue?
Here's the Page_Load function if it helps:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
      ///some code here that throws an exception
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
       LogStr("In catch block");
       return;
    }
}

TIA!

May I ask why you're using WebForms in 2024?

Your app is probably bouncing back to the login page because the authentication didn't take hold. Make sure the forms authentication cookie is being issued by the site and being presented by the browser with the next request.

@JohnWu You might be onto something.  I notice that in the working environments, ASP.NET_SessionID gets set when you navigate to the login page.  In the nonworking environment, it does not.  I compared IIS' "Session State" sections in both environments and they are identical.  Any ideas where else to look?

@Dai Its an ancient app for sure.  My job is to keep it up & running until its replacement goes live early next year.

The simplest explanation is the session cookie has the wrong domain, but that is just a guess. I suggest you look at the actual HTTP traffic to see which cookie headers are being sent in both directions.

You mentioned that there is no explicit redirection in the code, so how is your logic code for verifying identity login designed? Where is the session state set?

In web.config, I changed <httpCookies ... requireSSL="true" /> to `<httpCookies ... requireSSL=false" />.  This did the trick.  Thanks for the help!
